# INSERT ... VALUES using SELECT query

Tags: mysql

This is my table :

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

And this is an existing table `user` :

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

Now, I want to `INSERT` into `my_table` using values from table `user`.

Using this query :

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, firstname, lastname) 
VALUES (NULL, (SELECT firstname, lastname FROM user) );
```

I get this error :

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

How to do to insert using select query and auto_increment values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, firstname, lastname) 
SELECT NULL, firstname, lastname FROM user
```

or better

```
INSERT INTO my_table (firstname, lastname) 
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM user
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
INSERT INTO my_table (firstname, lastname) 
SELECT firstname, lastname FROM user;
```

Autoincrement will be manage by first table, where you defined it.